# How do you solve a differential equation with a definite integral inside of it?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, arc-length

$$
80=\int_0^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx
$$
($b$ is a nonzero constant)

Context: I was trying to do the amazon cable question (my friend sent it to me, I know the answer is zero, but I wanted to know how to do this still), and I tried using the arc length integral formula to figure out more about $f(x)$ (which I set to be the graph of the cable between the posts). The problem gives the length of the cable, and so this question arose.

Comment: What is "the amazon cable question"? Please include more background about how you originally got to this formula - for instance, what is $f$?

Comment: For anyone curious, here is the Amazon Cable Question: https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2018/07/12/can-you-solve-amazons-hanging-cable-interview-question/.

Comment: There are all kinds of functions satifying this equation. One such function   $f(x)=cx$ for a  suitable value of $c$.

Comment: Do you want to solve the catenary problem ?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I'm trying to isolate f'(x) and potentially solve for f(x).